# What would happen if I try to create Community User but I reached the limit already?

Tags: apex, customer-community

I would like to know what would happen if I try to create a Community user through Apex but I have already used all of my Licenses. What would be the result/error?

Comment: Why don't you try it out in a sandbox or dev org?

Answer (score 2):

You should get a DmlException that would have a status code of LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED. You should be able to try-catch this exception like all normal exceptions.